# How to teleport a player two block on his left?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I tried several things, like using vectors, but It didn't work for me. Than I tried searching on the internet and it didn't work as well.

```
Vector direc = l.getDirection().normalize();
direc.setY(l.getY());
direc.normalize();
direc.multiply(-1);
l.add(direc);

Player#teleport(l.getBlock().getLocation());
// or
Player#teleport(l);
```

Comment: Try to provide a more general title, how should another user know what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Location location = player.getLocation();
Vector direction = location.getDirection();
direction.normalize();

float newZ = (float)(location.getZ() + (2 *  Math.sin(Math.toRadians(location.getYaw() + 90 * direction)))); //2 is your block amount in Z direction
 
float newX = (float)(location.getX() + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(location.getYaw() + 90 * direction))));
```

You have to know in which direction you want to teleport the player

Answer (score 1):

Use [Vector#rotateAroundY](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/util/Vector.html#rotateAroundY-double-)​ to rotate the player's direction vector 90 degrees to the left.

```
Vector dir = player.getLocation().getDirection();     // get player's direction vector
dir.setY(0).normalize();                              // get rid of the y component
dir.rotateAroundY(Math.PI / 2);                       // rotate it 90 degrees to the left
dir.multiply(2);                                      // make the vector's length 2
Location newLocation = player.getLocation().add(dir); // add the vector to the player's location to get the new location
```